# How to group items without to using group by, unique or distinct?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I know the easy way is to use group by but there is a problem with Laravel and "Group By" due to security problems databases, I can fix the problem changing this parameter to false:
[config/database.app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXQv8.png)
But I prefer not do it (or tell me if I'm exaggerating).
I tried with distinct and unique but as you know, these only show only the column that you are grouping.
This is my table:
[Table Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGXFD.jpg)
I want to group by company_agreement_id but at same time I want to get the id and use it in other block.

So, what to use instead of this:

```
$test = DB::select("SELECT id,company_agreement_id 
FROM company_agreement_historicals 
WHERE ((`expiration_date` > ? and `status` = ?) or `status` = ?) 
GROUP BY company_agreement_id", ['2023-09-04 11:19:05', 2, 1]);
```

Thank you and forgive me if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: you need to define with an aggregation  function which defines which id you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group_concat for that that :

```php
$companyAgreementHistoricals = DB::select("SELECT group_concat(id) as ids,company_agreement_id 
FROM company_agreement_historicals 
WHERE ((`expiration_date` > ? and `status` = ?) or `status` = ?) 
GROUP BY company_agreement_id", ['2023-09-04 11:19:05', 2, 1]);
```

and then you can juste explode the concatenated results in php :

```php
$ids = explode(',', $companyAgreementHistorical->ids);
```

Also when using group_concat, you won't need to turn off strict mode.

In strict mode you can't have fields in select that are not part of the group by.

And on a side note, i recommend you to use eloquent models or the query builder for your queries.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it about combine group_concat and group by, it works, I got the ids with a foreach due to index of each item. About you recommendation, I already use them, this query was the quick way for post it. Thank you so much again!